# Missing div elements when downloading html using WebClient

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I'm currently trying to get a div element on [this page](https://glossary.infil.net/?t=dmslkadmsak), specifically this html code block:

```
<div id="glossary-space">
 <div class="noresults">No results.</div>
</div>
```

But when I try and download the page using Weblcient, it comes out like so:

`<div id="glossary-space"></div>`

I'm using this line of code to download the page.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{

    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
}
```

Comment: It seems likely you're dealing with a single page application or a page that loads data asynchronously using javascript. I imagine if you turn off Javascript in your browser, you'll see the same result as `WebClient`.

Comment: I would suggest simply parsing the [JSON](https://glossary.infil.net/json/glossary.json) used to build the glossary rather than browser automation as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think of doing that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're not seeing

```
<div id="glossary-space">
 <div class="noresults">No results.</div>
</div>
```

When you use the .DownloadString() method is because WebClient doesn't parse javascript.  The div for no results (as shown above) is inserted by the following code in glossary.js (around line 296) if the glossary is empty.

```
if(termlist.length == 0) {
    var empty = document.createElement('div');
    empty.setAttribute('class','noresults');
    empty.innerHTML = 'No results.';
    //document.getElementById('glossary-space').appendChild(document.createTextNode("No results"));
    document.getElementById('glossary-space').appendChild(empty);
}
```

On the flip-side even if you were to enter a URL with contents (such as https://glossary.infil.net/?t=KI) it would still just return

Since that data is also loaded by javascript.  In this type of situation it would probably be best to use a webdriver such as [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) that can make use of javascript.